# how to detect when a file is put in one of my folders

Tags: c#, events, filesystemwatcher

in my software I'm going to receive in one of my folders an XML file and a PDF file so i want to launch an event to read the XML so i can manage this files.

how can i detect this event, can u suggest me a book about events or a page, maybe gimme an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to watch a File System for change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317571/how-to-watch-a-file-system-for-change)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) .

```
void foo()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = "C:\\temp";
    watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
    watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
    watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";
}

void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   //handle created
}

void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Handle changed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned before, [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) is **the** way to go.

note, however, that there are a few subtleties to it: the `Created` event is raised once per file created, but it is raised as soon as the file first appears in the folder.  if you have a different process that copies that file, perhaps over a network connection, if you try to access the file while handling the `Created` event, you may get an exception.

Also note that the `Changed` event is most likely going to be raised multiple times if another process is copying a file in the folder you're watching.  Use the [`NotifyFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) to reduce the number of events that are raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to watch that folder for XML files.